# Is a Text Gradient similar to Cufon possible using CSS3 & @font-face?

Tags: css, font-face, cufon

Using @font-face and CSS3 I want to simulate the linear gradient that you can achieve on text using Cufon

> color: '-linear-gradient(#7f7f7f, #616161)',

I have the webkit rule

> -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#7F7F7F), to(#616161));

but can't seem to get it to apply to the text using the color: selector or any other variation. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I tried doing the same without any luck. Maybe gradients aren't supported on the color property? Keen to see if someone has it working.

Comment: You can create an inverted font and apply a gradient background image (the gradient would show through the "holes" in the font, and be obscured elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to do it in webkit browsers. See this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-pure-css-text-gradients/